# How can I avoid re-rendering of the parent components of a nested child-route with React Router 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is one my Routes:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="A">
    <Route path=":date" element={
      <Wrapper>
        <ProviderB>
          <Summary />
      </ProviderB>
    </Wrapper>
    }
    />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

This is **Wrapper**:

```
export const Wrapper: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
   return (
       <ProviderA>
         {children}
       </ProviderA>
   );
};
```

This is component **ProviderA**:

```
const ContextAction = createContext({
  ...
});

const ContextValue = createContext({
  ...
});

export const ProviderA: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
   const [state, setState] = useState('');

  return (
    <ContextAction.Provider value={setState}>
      <ContextValue.Provider value={state}>
        {children}
      </ContextValue.Provider>
    </ContextAction.Provider>
  );
};
```

And this is component **ProviderB**:

```
const ContextAction = createContext({
  ...
});

const ContextValue = createContext({
  ...
});

export const ProviderB: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {
   const [state, setState] = useState('');

  return (
    <ContextAction.Provider value={setState}>
      <ContextValue.Provider value={state}>
        {children}
      </ContextValue.Provider>
    </ContextAction.Provider>
  );
};
```

What I want to achieve is to render only **Summary** when the date in the URL does change. For example, a URL change from A/26-01-2024 to A/25-01-2014 should not trigger the re-rendering of **Wrapper**; instead it should re-render only the child-nested route **Summary**. How may I achieve that by using `<Outlet />`?
Hopefully, the above makes sense even if it is tricky.

Comment: What's your driver for wanting to prevent rerenders?

Comment: It might be something of fetching data from API on every single wrapper rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is to render only Summary when the date in the
> URL does change.

This is just how React works. If you don't want `ProviderA` and `ProviderB` to rerender when the route rerenders then move them higher up the ReactTree.

I suggest creating a layout route that renders the providers and an `Outlet` for the nested routes.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const ProviderLayout = () => (
  <ProviderA>
    <ProviderB>
      <Outlet />
    </ProviderB>
  </ProviderA>
);
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="A">
    <Route element={<ProviderLayout />}>
      <Route path=":date" element={<Summary />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

If rerendering is still an issue then continue pushing the providers higher and higher up the ReactTree until they are being rendered from a stable component that doesn't rerender when the route(s) rerender(s).

Comment: Have amended a bit my question so that it represents exactly my code. So, if you could have a look...

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper I believe my answer still stands. If you don't want `Wrapper` to rerender when the `path=":date"` route rerenders (*because the `date` path parameter changed*) then move it higher in the ReactTree. Have you tried the solution I suggest? Do you need a running code example to be convinced?

Comment: It seems <Summary /> is not the only component to re-render.  I want to understand what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Maybe a running code example would help.

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper How exactly are you verifying a component rerender? Can you check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-mopsa-f6tkyk?file=/src/App.js) demo? When navigating between the "date" routes note that only the `Summary` component logs that it rendered.

Comment: Something is wrong with the codesandbox link.

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper Ugh, sorry about that, codesandbox is going through some changes right now and apparently sandboxes are now private by default. Can you try that link now?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper Have you had a chance to try the solution out and/or check the sandbox?

Comment: I have started a bounty of 150 points for that question, however this was not visible and could not reward it to you. The thing is they deducted those 150 points from my account. Any idea what should I do?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper AFAIK Bounties are basically "use it or lose it". If the bounty isn't awarded, manually or by automatic thresholds, I'm not sure there's anything you can do. You might try a custom mod flag on your post and plead your case, but even then I don't know if there's anything they could do.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your  into:

```
function compare(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return (prevProps.location.pathname == nextProps.location.pathname)
}
export default withRouter(React.memo(Wrapper, compare));
```